# I can't login docker using nginx as reverse proxy server for nexus

Tags: docker, nginx, nexus

I have environment builded with docker-compose. Nexus website is working fine but I can't login with docker.

This is the error I get when I try to log in

> C:\Users\j0nl1>docker login repository.localhost
>
> Username: admin
>
> Password:
>
> Error response from daemon: Get
> http://repository.localhost/v2/: dial tcp:  lookup
> repository.localhost on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host

My default.conf file:

```
worker_processes 2;

events { 
    worker_connections 1024; 
}

http {
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    access_log  /dev/null;
    proxy_intercept_errors off;
    proxy_send_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;

    server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:3000;
    }
}
    
    upstream nexus {
        server nexus:8081;
    }

    upstream registry {
        server nexus:8082;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name repository.localhost;

        keepalive_timeout  5 5;
        proxy_buffering    off;

        # allow large uploads
        client_max_body_size 1G;

        location / {
        # redirect to docker registry
        if ($http_user_agent ~ docker ) {
            proxy_pass http://registry;
        }
        proxy_pass http://nexus;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: './web'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  
  nexus:
    build: './nexus'
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "8082:8082"
      - "8083:8083"
    volumes:
      - c:/docker/nexus:/nexus-data
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - web
      - nexus
```

Nexus DockerFile:

```
FROM sonatype/nexus3:3.17.0

EXPOSE 8081-8083
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your host file

```
127.0.0.1 repository.localhost
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that work perfectly. I just have one doubt why this url was accesible from the browser but it wasn't accesible from docker?

Comment: Are you sure the browser did not open to http://127.0.0.1/ ? I have no way to explain otherwise. I am assuming browser on the same machine.

Comment: Yes the browser is on the same machine. I would say it didn't open to 127.0.0.1 mainly because I have the web container pointing to that direction. For that reason I thought it wasn't necessary to add repository.localhost to my hosts file because it was already accesible from web browser.